# DeviceCheck: Unable to verify authorization token

Tags: python, ios, authentication, jwt, devicecheck

I’m trying to get **DeviceCheck** to work, where I keep getting this response from Apple’s server:  `401 Unable to verify authorization token`.

The `device_token` is being sent to my python server over a base64 encoded string in JSON payload. Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Here is my code example:

```
def device_check_query(device_token):  
    data = {  
        'device_token': device_token,  
        'transaction_id': str(uuid4()),  
        'timestamp': int(time.time() * 1000),  
    }  
    jw_token = get_jw_token()  
    headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + jw_token}  
    response = requests.post(QUERY_URL, json=data, headers=headers)  
    return response.content

def get_jw_token():  
    with open(KEY_FILE, 'r') as cert_file:  
        certificate = cert_file.read()  

    jw_token = jwt.encode(  
        {'iss': TEAM_ID}, certificate,  
        algorithm='ES256',  
        headers={'kid': KEY_ID})  

    return jw_token
```

Comment: my original question here https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/312475#312475

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

you need to add in the payload the issuer key and iat then it will work, check my code below

```
import time
def device_check_query(device_token):  
    data = {  
        'device_token': device_token,  
        'transaction_id': str(uuid.uuid4()),  
        'timestamp': int(time.time() * 1000),  
    }  
    jw_token = get_jw_token()  
    headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + jw_token}  
    response = requests.post(url, json=data, headers=headers)  
    return response.content

def get_jw_token():  
    with open('myfile.p8', 'r') as cert_file:  
        certificate = cert_file.read()  
    jw_token = jwt.encode(  
        {'iss': issuer,'iat': int(time.time())}, certificate,  
        algorithm='ES256',  
        headers={'kid': keyid})  
    return jw_token
device_check_query(u"1234e323a22133....")
```

Comment: keyFileName = ""; // Download from https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/authkey/ 

keyId = ""; // Can be found at: https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/authkey/


TeamId = ""; // Can be found at: https://developer.apple.com/account/#/membership/

Comment: Also worth noting that only device tokens generated from apps with explicit provisioning profiles will work. Wildcard profiles do not.